# How to iterate an associative array

Tags: autohotkey, associative-array

If I have the following associative array how do I cycle through each element of the array. So that I can print out each element

```
arr :=  {Name:MyName,Email:MyEmailAddress,Date:TheDate}
```

I have tried the following:

```
enum := arr._NewEnum()
While enum[key, value]
{
    t .= key "=" value "`n"
}

MsgBox % t
```

But nothing is displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't storing strings in the array, but variables that weren't defined, so nothing is displayed.

Store strings and/or numbers:

```
arr :=  {Name:"MyName",Email:"MyEmailAddress",Date:1234567}
```

Then use a for loop:

```
for key, value in arr
{
    MsgBox, %key% = %value%
}
```